# Dropped database mongodb on linux (ubuntu). Find who done this

Tags: linux, mongodb

Someone enter to my serwer and run drop all databases in mongodb.
From log of mongodb i found commands:

```
Thu Jan  5 01:44:46.439 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 95.211.184.210:38159 #547644 (98 connections now open)
Thu Jan  5 01:44:46.576 [conn547644] dropDatabase local starting Thu Jan  5 01:44:46.578 [conn547644] removeJournalFiles
Thu Jan  5 01:44:46.584 [conn547644] dropDatabase local finished
Thu Jan  5 01:44:46.601 [conn547644] dropDatabase xxxx0 starting
Thu Jan  5 01:44:46.601 [conn547644] removeJournalFiles
Thu Jan  5 01:44:46.616 [conn547644] dropDatabase xxxx0 finished
Thu Jan  5 01:44:46.633 [conn547644] dropDatabase xxxx1 starting
Thu Jan  5 01:44:46.633 [conn547644] removeJournalFiles
Thu Jan  5 01:44:46.844 [conn547644] dropDatabase xxxx1 finished
Thu Jan  5 01:44:46.844 [conn547644] command xxxx1.$cmd command: { dropDatabase: 1.0 } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) W:211545 reslen:62 211ms
Thu Jan  5 01:44:46.861 [conn547644] dropDatabase xxxx2 starting
Thu Jan  5 01:44:46.861 [conn547644] removeJournalFiles
Thu Jan  5 01:44:46.883 [conn547644] dropDatabase xxxx2 finished
Thu Jan  5 01:44:46.900 [conn547644] dropDatabase xxxx3 starting
Thu Jan  5 01:44:46.900 [conn547644] removeJournalFiles
Thu Jan  5 01:44:46.919 [conn547644] dropDatabase xxxx3 finished
Thu Jan  5 01:44:46.936 [conn547644] dropDatabase xxxx4 starting
Thu Jan  5 01:44:46.936 [conn547644] removeJournalFiles
Thu Jan  5 01:44:46.939 [conn547644] dropDatabase xxxx4 finished
Thu Jan  5 01:44:46.995 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /data/mongodb/WARNING.ns, filling with zeroes...
Thu Jan  5 01:44:46.998 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile /data/mongodb/WARNING.ns, size: 16MB,  took 0.002 secs
Thu Jan  5 01:44:46.998 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /data/mongodb/WARNING.0, filling with zeroes...
Thu Jan  5 01:44:47.000 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile /data/mongodb/WARNING.0, size: 64MB,  took 0.001 secs
Thu Jan  5 01:44:47.000 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /data/mongodb/WARNING.1, filling with zeroes...
Thu Jan  5 01:44:47.002 [conn547644] build index WARNING.WARNING { _id: 1 }
Thu Jan  5 01:44:47.002 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile /data/mongodb/WARNING.1, size: 128MB,  took 0.002 secs
Thu Jan  5 01:44:47.002 [conn547644] build index done.  scanned 0 total records. 0 secs
Thu Jan  5 01:44:47.056 [conn547644] end connection 95.211.184.210:38159 (97 connections now open)
```

I have only IP and conn number. Ip looks like from Netherlands (i think someone used proxy to fake this connection). Is there any way to find out more details about that user 547644 ? Maybe by what key he logged into system ? Maybe there is some way to restore deleted files from database ?

Comment: do you have backups of your DB ?

Comment: Yes i have backup of database

Comment: I have the same issue, all databases in mongodb was dropped and i found WARNING.ns file in data directory. I also use ubuntu (digital ocean hosting).

Comment: Here the same, digitalocean, mongodb, website empty of data and these annoyng WARNING file. The problem is that i've no backup. There is a way to restore deleted files from the database?

Comment: In my case as used IP 95.211.184.210:39898, from NL too

Comment: relevant: "MongoDB Databases being Targeted by Cyber-criminals for Ransom" https://www.hackread.com/mongodb-databases-for-ransom/

Comment: it happened to me too !! DigitalOcean too!!!